# Drupal show breadcrumbs on certain nodes

Tags: uri, breadcrumbs, nodes

I've been using the path by bread crumbs module (https://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs), which allows me to create bread crumbs based on nodes. However the page the crumb is on, shows the title of the crumb.

Example: Home>>Node_Title

I want the Home crumb, but not the Node_Title (I'ts a long title as well).

This is what I want:

Node 36 URL= TitleExample

Breadcrumb example for Node 36: Home>> (no node URL)

Does this make sense?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the path breadcrumbs module it doesn't append the title to the end unless you add it yourself when configuring the breadcrumbs.

It is quite possible that what is adding the title is your theme.

For example the zen theme has an option to show the page title at the end of the breadcrumbs, as do lots of other themes.

To get to these settings, on your site go to admin/appearance and then click the settings link for whichever is your theme.

Comment: and your right. I am using zen :)